# Qt tab widget add corner group widget

Tags: qt

I want to add a group widget to the corner of tab widget. so i wrote these below, but doesn't work.

```
auto layout = new QHBoxLayout;
auto text = new QTextEdit;
auto button = new QPushButton("find");
layout->addWidget(text);
layout->addWidget(button);

auto group = new QGroupBox;
group->setLayout(layout);

stageTabWidget->setCornerWidget(group);
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the group was too small to show the widget. Change the style of the group with this line:

```
group->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox"
                     "{"
                        "border:0px;"
                        "padding-top:-10px;"
                        "padding-bottom:-10px;"
                     "}");
```